# How do I bend cheese?

Tags: food

My friend told me that cheese could be bent and there is foldable cheese. I've tried folding it but it breaks, I tried heating it slightly but it still breaks.
How can I fold cheese?

Thanks.

Comment: This is the greatest question I have ever seen.

Comment: I just don't see why I get downvotes for a completely reasonable question... I tried everything, so I needed help thinking **outside the box** @MrPhooky

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your friend was teasing you. Not all cheeses can be folded. You will probably have the greatest success with "KRAFT™" process cheese due to its plastic consistency. (Maybe that stuff ***IS*** plastic.) Fermented or natural brick cheeses like cheddar are too dry or flakey to slice thin enough to fold. Some foldable cheese needs to be put on a sheet of parchment paper before it is folded. Then, by folding the parchment you avoid the break. You cannot get a sharp crease with cheese, as it will break when you push down on the fold. At best, all you can expect is a loose round fold. After you fold the cheese a first time, there is no way to fold it again unless you put butter, margarine, or some lubricant to allow the cheese layers to slide upon each other as it is folded or it will break. Warming the cheese will help somewhat. Yellow process cheese folds more easily than the white. Swiss process cheese is the bendyest(?) of all. When you get more practice, cheese origami is a demanding artform practiced by very few. (I am kidding about the origami with cheese; but, who knows?)

Comment: There are also very soft cheeses like brie that bend easily. It's nearly a liquid.

Comment: Hard to slice brie or camembert. They moosh. They moosh nice, though.

Comment: yeah, young brie/camembert will bend, except for the crust.